# How to make gradient fillStyle

Tags: javascript, visualization, gradient

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- <video class="video" src="Comp 1_3.mp4" autoplay loop muted preload="auto" height="3000px" width="3000px"></video> -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="beat.css">
        <title>Something!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
        <img src = "image0.jpg" width="300px" height="300px">
        <h1><div class = "title">Camry</div></h1>
        <audio class="audio" id="audio" src="UncleFlexxx - Camry 3.5.mp3" controls></audio>
        <div class="information">
                    <div class = "bpm"><?php echo "<h3>BPM:</h3></div>
        <div class = "tags"><?php echo "<h3>Теги:</h3></div>
        <div class = "price"><?php echo "<h2>Цена:</h2></div>
        <div class = "views"><?php echo "<h4>Просмотры:</h4></div>
    </div>

        <div class = "description"><?php echo "<h3>Описание:</h3> <h4>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A harum, sequi repellat obcaecati pariatur accusantium nostrum at recusandae repellendus maxime mollitia molestias, tempora facilis? Aliquid ducimus sunt est, animi earum voluptatum magnam consequatur non aut ratione ad, hic incidunt voluptatibus accusamus in, nulla rerum eius nihil deleniti commodi ex laudantium mollitia. Repellendus quaerat, tenetur quod dolorem expedita aut assumenda quam inventore sit molestiae reprehenderit veritatis odio necessitatibus, veniam nostrum praesentium adipisci recusandae ipsam fuga, cupiditate sapiente amet atque corrupti voluptatibus!</h4></div>
        <div class="info">
                     <div class = "author"><h3>Автор:<a href = "/hprofile.php?user_id=<?php echo $author_id; ?>"><h3>долбаеб</h3></a></div>
                     <div class = "publication_date"><?php echo "<h3>Дата публикации: Эбланская</h3></div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="720"></canvas>
        </div>
        <button><a href = "<?php echo $beatlocation; ?>" download>Купить за <?php echo $price; ?>$</a></button>
        <form method = "POST" action = "/addcomment.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
        <button type = "submit" name = "comment">Оставить комментарий</button>
        <input type = "text" name = "comment_txt" placeholder = "Оставить комментарий">
        <h2><div class = "comments">Комментарии:</div></h2>
        </form>
            <script>
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                    function getPos(Hz, minHz, maxHz, max) {
                        if (Hz > minHz) {
                            var posMin = Math.log10(minHz) * max;
                            return (Math.log10(Hz) - Math.log10(minHz)) * max / (Math.log10(maxHz) - Math.log10(minHz));
                        } else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    function getFFTbars(fft, barCount) {
                        var minHz = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : 20;
                        var maxHz = arguments.length > 3 && arguments[3] !== undefined ? arguments[3] : 12000;
                        var dataArray = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
                        fft.getFloatFrequencyData(dataArray);
                        var pos;
                        var out = [];
                        for (i in dataArray) {
                            pos = Math.round(getPos(i * 24000 / dataArray.length, minHz, maxHz, barCount));
                            if (pos < barCount) if (!out[pos] || out[pos] < dataArray[i]) out[pos] = dataArray[i];
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i < barCount; i++) {
                            if (!out[i]) {
                                var prevIndex = void 0,
                                    prevValue = void 0;
                                if ((prevIndex = i - 1) < 0) {
                                    prevIndex = 0;
                                    prevValue = 0;
                                } else {
                                    prevValue = out[prevIndex];
                                }
                                var nextIndex = void 0,
                                    nextValue = void 0;
                                for (var k = i; k < barCount; k++) {
                                    if (out[k]) {
                                        nextIndex = k;
                                        nextValue = out[k];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!nextIndex) {
                                    nextIndex = barCount - 1;
                                    nextValue = 0;
                                }
                                out[i] = prevValue + (nextValue - prevValue) / (nextIndex - prevIndex);
                            }
                        }
                        return out;
                    }
                    function draw() {
                        var bars = getFFTbars(analyser, 120);
                        canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        canvasCtx.fillStyle = "blue";
                        canvasCtx.beginPath();
                        for (i in bars) {
                            canvasCtx.rect(i * 10, canvas.height - (bars[i] + 64) * canvas.height / 64, 8, canvas.height);
                        }
                        canvasCtx.fill();
                    }
                    var canvas, canvasCtx, audioCtx, source, analyser, bufferLength, dataArray, gainNode;
                    var initialized = false;
                    audio.addEventListener('play', function () {
                        if (!initialized) {
                            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                            canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                            audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
                            source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                            analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
                            analyser.fftSize = 8192;
                            bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
                            dataArray = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
                            gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
                            source.connect(analyser);
                            source.connect(gainNode);
                            gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                            setInterval(draw, 8);
                            initialized = true;
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </main>
    </body>


</html>
```

I want to make visualization be blue and red like gradient. I tried to create gradient by
gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 460, 0)
gradient.addColorStop(0.00, 'red')
but it doest work. I didn't find information I need to solve this problem.
I want the gradient to go from top to bottom. Blue above and yellow below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
gradient.addColorStop(p, 'red')
```

p represents the percentage form where the gradient will start. Use (0.0, "blue") and (0.5,"yellow").

after creating the gradient you have to assign it to an rectangle by using:

```js
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, x1, y1);
```

For more information you can consult [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient).